# Problems building hyperscan

Tags: cmake

I am attempting to build hyperscan: https://github.com/01org/hyperscan on ubuntu 16.04.  I have installed the listed prerequisites and I am now using Cmake to create the build scripts which gives the following error:

```
...
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- looking for sqlite3 in source tree
CMake Error at cmake/sqlite3.cmake:25 (message):
no sqlite3 in source tree
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  tools/hsbench/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/rful011/hyperscan/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/rful011/hyperscan/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The tails of the two Cmake Files have nothing related to sqlite -- they deal with the thread stuff.

I installed the libsqlite3-dev package but that made no difference.  I am not familiar with Cmake (with configure I would be looking at fiddling with options to specify library locations...) so I am at a loss on how to proceed.
I did find the sqlite.cmake file and it appears to check for installed module (which presumably failed) and then it looks in the source tree.3

Comment: I was going to write a detailed answer, but I've noticed that you said you installed `libsqlite-dev` - `libsqlite3-dev` is the correct package. Is this just a typo?

Comment: my bad!  it is libsqlite3-dev...

Comment: So, which is the typo? You have actually installed `libsqlite3-dev`? BTW, I just followed the instructions for building from `git`, and it works for me on Ubuntu 14.04...

Comment: yes Ken, I installed libsqlite3-dev and I have now updated the question to reflect that .  I also did a rm -r * in the build directory to make sure there was nothing laying around from the run before I installed sqlite3.

Comment: I wonder what it is searching for when looking for sqlite3?  I have /usr/include/sqlite3.h.  This is a new VM so it should not have accrued any cruft!    What I am really after here is ideas on how to find out what cmake is actually doing.

Comment: Could you try running `pkg-config --print-errors --print-provides sqlite3`? This is basically what CMake is trying to do internally - I get `sqlite3 = 3.8.2`. Also, `pkg-config --debug sqlite3` might give a hint - ignore everything until the `Looking for package 'sqlite3'` line.

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be that pkg-config was not installed and installing it fixed the issue.

I was looking at the cmake file and guessed that "find_package(PkgConfig QUIET)" called pktconfig and when I checked it was not installed.

Hope this helps someone in the future!